# Mounted Xen image does not sync with actual drive

Tags: linux, mount, xen

I have mounted a xen guest partition on /dev/mapper/vg01. 
I also create a file let say in /home/user/a.txt

then I also ssh to the guest server and create file in /home/user/b.txt
in the terminal i did not see a.txt, b.txt

also the same in the mounted partition. i only see a.txt not b.txt

how can i fix this ? or maybe there is some other way for me to change the file ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't mount a non distributed local filesystem from multiple locations at the same time, you'll end up corrupting it.